# Required field validation on group of text box Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to apply required field validation on text box group in which at least one text box group must contain value.
in bellow image, details of at least one bank must be filled.

[image]

I have used jquery-form-validator plugin from http://www.formvalidator.net/#custom-validators and created custome validator as bellow, but Its not working.

```
   $("#txtBankDetails")
   .valAttr('error-msg', 'select atlest 1 bankname.');


   $.formUtils.addValidator({       
    name: 'data-text-group',
    validatorFunction: function (value, $el, config, language, $form) {
        debugger
        var isValid = true,
     // get name of element. since it is a checkbox group, all checkboxes will have same name
       elname = $el.attr('data-text-group'),
     // get checkboxes and count the checked ones
       $textBoxes = $('input[type=textbox][data-text-group^="' + elname + '"]', $form),

        nonEmptyCount = $textBoxes.filter(function () {
            return !!this.value;
        }).length;

        alert(nonEmptyCount);
        if (nonEmptyCount == 0) {
            isValid = false;
        }

    }
});
  // Setup form validation only on the form having id "registration"
$.validate({

    form: '#registration',
    modules: 'date, security, file, logic',
    validateOnBlur: true,
    showHelpOnFocus: true,
    addSuggestions: true,
    onModulesLoaded: function () {
        console.log('All modules loaded!');
    },
    onSuccess: function ($form) {
        form.submit();
        alert("sucess")
        return false;
    },
    onError: function () {
        alert("Error")
    }
});
```

html code is,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/theme-default.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

   <form id="registration" method="post" action="@Url.Action("NewRegistration", "StaticPage")" enctype="multipart/form-data" class='has-validation-callback'>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="txtBankDetails" name="Bankname1" data-text-group="BankName" placeholder="01. BANK NAME" data-validation-error-msg="select atlest 1 bankname.">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="nwresmainfild" name="BankACNo1" placeholder="BANK A/C NO.">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input class="nwresmainfild" name="BankAddress1" placeholder="BANK ADDRESS">
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="txtBankDetails" name="Bankname2" data-text-group="BankName" placeholder="01. BANK NAME" data-validation-error-msg="select atlest 1 bankname.">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input  name="BankACNo2" placeholder="BANK A/C NO.">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input name="BankAddress2" placeholder="BANK ADDRESS">
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="txtBankDetails" name="Bankname3" data-text-group="BankName" placeholder="03. BANK NAME" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input  name="BankACNo3" placeholder="BANK A/C NO.">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input  name="BankAddress3" placeholder="BANK ADDRESS">
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
   <input value="PROCESS & PRINT" class="green-btn uppercase" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Define "it's not working" - Errors in the console?

Comment: Would be very helpful if you create a fiddle for this. 
Need to check the DOM structure.

Comment: From what I can see from your HTML code, you don't even have a `<form>` with id `registration`. Have you given us all the code you've written? Or have you literally missed creating the actual form?